# Python file in C++ interface

Tags: python, c++, speech-recognition

My team and I were assigned different tasks. Some of my team implemented the interface with other parts using C++ language. On the other hand, I was assigned to implement speech recognition. When I did my research, I found that most of the speech recognition was in python, so I successfully used the speech recognition libraries to implement the program. The problem now is that we need to use the speech recognition which is in python in the C++ interface. I found many ways to convert Python to C++ such as Cython and more. Is this the only way or are there other options? Also, is there a speech recognition library in C++? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which operating system?  Windows has a rather competent speech recognition engine built-in.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am using IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed python in the C++ application.  Here is an [example lesson](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/820116/embedding-python-program-in-a-c-cplusplus-code) and [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html).

I have done this where I wanted a user to be able to customize a solver.  In that case I had the user write a python function then my app loads and runs it from C++.

The only real roadblock I ran into in the past was making sure the C++ application can find it.  Then when you link the application you need to link to the python libraries and at runtime your app needs to access the appropriate python library files depending on the OS.